# Angular 5 ERROR in _this.host.getOutputName is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I really don't know why but when I upgraded from Angular 4 => 5, `ng serve` doesn't seem to be working and is throwing an error:

> ERROR in _this.host.getOutputName is not a function
>
> webpack: Failed to compile.

This is what my package looks like:

```
{
  "name": "website",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ngx-textarea-autosize": "^1.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.16",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's known issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21621

Consider installing the same versions of angular dependencies:

```
"@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
```

but then in your devDependencies I see

```
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
```

Comment: After changing it to `^5.0.0` and running `npm install`, now I have an error saying `Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is "5.2.3".` . I tried changing it to `^5.2.3` as well but no luck

Comment: Remove `node_modules` and `packages.lock` file and install again. You can also take all versions from default @angular/cli project

Answer (score 1):

try setting

```
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0"
```

in your devDependencies